# Is it possible to run PHP code on second click on a button and not imidiately on first click?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Situation: I've a toggle_btn (switches Start / Stop --> value of the btn changes). When the page loads the value of the button is Start. When I hit the btn, the btn will toggle to Stop. The problem is that my php code runs when i hit the button for the first time (when i hit start), but I want the php code to be executed on the second click, when i click on Stop.

Is it possible to run the php code on second click on a btn?

**HTML CODE**:

```
<div id="row3">
    <form action="./includes/insert_data.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return check();">
        <div id="zone_area">
            <p><input type="text" name="zone_field" id="zone_field" placeholder="Enter a zone" autocomplete="off"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="button_area">
            <p><input type="submit" value="Start" id="toggle_btn" name="toggle_btn"></p>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript CODE

```
function check(){
    var zone_field = document.getElementById("zone_field");

    if(zone_field.value == ''){
        alert("Try again");
        return false;
    } else {
        second_check();
    }
}

function second_check(){
    var toggle_btn = document.getElementById("toggle_btn");

    if(counter == 0){

        //zone_field.disabled = true;
        toggle_btn.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        toggle_btn.style.border = "1px solid black";
        toggle_btn.value = "Stop";
        toggle_btn.style.transition = "all 0.2s ease";

        counter = 1;
    } else {
        var zone_table = document.getElementById("zone_table");
        var avg_div = document.getElementById("row5");

        //zone_field.disabled = false;
        toggle_btn.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        toggle_btn.value = "Start";
        toggle_btn.style.transition = "all 0.2s ease";

        $(avg_div).slideDown(300);
        zone_table.innerHTML = zone_field.value;

        zone_field.value = '';

        counter = 0;
    } 
}
```

**PHP CODE**:

```
<?php

include_once("./conn.php");

if(isset($_POST["toggle_btn"])){
    if(!empty($_POST["zone_field"])){

        $sql = "SELECT SUM(waarde) AS total_sum, COUNT(waarde) AS total_count FROM results";
        $res = $conn->query($sql);

        $Name = $_POST["zone_field"];
        $Time = 10;

        if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {

                $avg = $row["total_sum"] / $row["total_count"];

                $sql = "INSERT INTO measurements (Name, Time, AVG_ms) VALUES(?, ?, ?);";
                
                if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
                    // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $Name, $Time, $avg);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                    
                    header("Location: ../results.php");
                } else{
                    echo "ERROR: Could not prepare query: $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
                }
            } 
        } else {
            echo "No rows have been found";
        }
        $conn->close();
    }
} else {
    echo 'Did not hit the btn';
}
?>
```

Comment: Yeah you can. On the first click set a variable, on the second click check if it's set and then proceed

Comment: @jrswgtr Is it possible to write it down bellow?

Comment: @CBroe I do need to use a submit button and not a regular button because i check if the user filled in the input text field or not.

Comment: You dont need a counter, just `if (document.getElementById("toggle_btn").value == 'Start') { event.preventDefault(); }`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ok thanks but the problem is that the PHP code runs first so this peace of js code will not be executed first

Comment: use a simple button, on click replace it with your submit button / other action

Answer (score 1):

You will need to keep track of if the button has been pressed before, if you want it to alternate between options depend if its stopping or starting you can do something like this

```
var numberOfClicks = 0; 

function clickHandler() { 
  numberOfClicks++;
  if (numberOfClicks % 2 == 1) {
    // Enters statement when clicks are odd eg 1, 3, 5 etc.  
    // Logic for when button is 'start'
  } else { 
    // Other numbers 2, 4, 6 etc.
    // Logiic for when button is 'stop'
  } 
}
```

Comment: Do in need to call this function as `onclick="clickHandler();"` in my input field?

Comment: Yes you would use this as the main handler for the click event on button(s) you want to trigger and then delegate to other functions etc. in the if blocks depending if its a first or second time clicking

Comment: Okey, i understand this way but, in your example your example you are working with a button, but how can i run the php script if i work with a button and not with a submit button, to sumbit the form? Because the javascript code needs to run before the php code (so on second click, the php script needs to be executed)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following JS code to control button's behaviour and then  call your PHP page:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("clickTwice");
button.onclick = () => {
    if (button.innerHTML !== "Click me again") {
        button.innerHTML = "Click me again";
    } else {
        button.innerHTML = "Submitted";
        // Do whatever you want, like sending data with fetch() or XMLHttpRequest().
    }
    return false;
};
```

```html
<button id="clickTwice">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.